# Custom css divs overlapping each other

Tags: css

I wish to create a dynamic page as per the attached blueprint but divs are somewhere overlapping and also need some improvements.
Need responsive layout and text of divs will not overlap each other while resizing.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.top-bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  bottom: 95%;
  border-style: dotted;
}
.right-panel-main {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90%;
  bottom: 5%;
  width: 20%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  border-style: dotted;
  position: absolute;
}
.left-panel-main {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90%;
  bottom: 5%;
  width: 80%;
  right: 20%;
  background-color: pink;
  border-style: dotted;
  position: absolute;
}
#section-panel-main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8%;
  border-style: dotted;
}
#response-button-panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8%;
  border-style: dotted;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.bottom-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  top: 95%;
  border-style: dotted;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="top-bar">j</div>
  <div class="left-panel-main">
    <div id="section-panel-main"></div>
    <div id="response-button-panel"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="right-panel-main">j</div>
  <div class="bottom-bar">j</div>
</div>
\
```

```
    <html>
<head> 
<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
overflow:hidden;

}

.top-bar
{
position: absolute;
width:100%;
height:5%;
bottom:95%;
border-style: dotted;
}

.right-panel-main
{
position: absolute;
height:90%;
bottom:5%;
width:20%;
right: 0;
background-color: red;
border-style: dotted;
position:absolute;
}
.left-panel-main
{
position: absolute;
height:90%;
bottom:5%;
width:80%;
right:20%;
background-color: pink;
border-style: dotted;
position:absolute;
}

#section-panel-main
{
width:100%;
height:8%;
border-style: dotted;
}

#response-button-panel
{
width:100%;
height:8%;
border-style: dotted;
bottom : 0;
position: absolute;
}
.bottom-bar
{
width:100%;
height:5%;
top:95%;
border-style: dotted;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;

}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="top-bar">j</div>
    <div class="left-panel-main">
        <div id="section-panel-main"></div>
        <div id="response-button-panel"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="right-panel-main">j</div>
    <div class="bottom-bar">j</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Description]

Comment: Giving a quick look at it your issue is a common one: using `position:absolute`. Try changing your `<div>` elements to use `box-sizing:border-box;` which may help with _some_ of the issues. Also, percentage heights don't work very well. You may want to consider what your `min-height` is and either use that as a default height or add it as the `min-height` attribute (referring to your top bar)

Comment: To avoid overlapping use float:left; and use position:relative; Think about sizes of each <div>. Learn about clear:both; css property.

Answer (score 1):

try this layout, perfectly responsive, of course for small devices you have to use media queries

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

*{
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;right:0;left:0;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}

#content{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left:0;right:0;
  bottom: 40px;
}

#container{
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 140px;/*width of sidebar*/
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

#section{
  height: 40px;
  background: coral;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left:0;right:0;
  bottom: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: green;
}

#buttom-panel {
  position: absolute;
  right:0;left:0;bottom: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#sidebar{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 140px;/*width of sidebar*/
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#footer{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  
  </head>
  
  
  <body>
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="section">section</div>
      <div id="main">scrollable</div>
      <div id="buttom-panel">buttom panel</div>
    </div>  
    <div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="footer">footer</div>
  
  
  
  
  </body>  
</html>
```